# Europe/Uzhgorod and Europe/Zaporozhye

Tags: php

Europe/Uzhgorod and Europe/Zaporozhye are not listing anymore as PHP valid timezones
https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

Any clues why?

Answer (score 3):

PHP uses the [timezone data provided by IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which is regularly updated.  The [September update](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2022-September/000073.html) notes:

> Briefly:
>
> Simplify three Ukraine zones into one.

and in more detail:

> Changes to past timestamps
>
> Simplify three Ukraine zones to one, since the post-1970
> differences seem to have been imaginary.  Move Europe/Uzhgorod and
> Europe/Zaporozhye to 'backzone'; backward-compatibility links
> still work, albeit with different timestamps before October 1991.